# Performance problem with upsert in mysql Aurora

Tags: mysql, upsert

I am posting here a performance problem which we are dealing with Upsert statement in MySQL Aurora database. The details are mentioned below.

Background Details:
Suppose if there is a schema db1 with a table called tab1(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6). There is unique index being created on col5 and col6.
We created a unique view in the schema db1 with the same structure as tab1 which has the latest data from tab1. And also there is a schema called db2 in which a table tab2 is created with the same 
structure of tab1 and unique index. The data from the unique view is inserted/updated into tab2 of schema db2 by using upsert statement. This process is followed on each and every day such that tab2 will have the latest data from tab1.

Problem:
For the first time, as there was no data available in tab2, the upsert statement executed very fast as expected. The second time when delta load has come to the unique view from the tab1 of schema db1. This incremental/delta data should be inserted and updated in the tab2 of schema db2 using upsert statement. The following upsert statement is taking very long time to execute. Not sure, why it is taking very long time. The syntax is as follows.

INSERT INTO tab2 SELECT v.*,CURDATE()
 FROM db1.uniqueview AS v ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
col1=v.col1,col2=v.col2, col3=v.col3, col4=v.col4;

Tab1 has around 2 million rows currently. This data is easily inserted into tab2 when we ran the above command, For the next incremental loads, upsert operation is very slow.

Please help in resolving the issue or your thoughts.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If this process is slow I would suspect your view is not picking the deltas (or there is a huge number of them) BTW why bother with a view?

Comment: In tab1, the unique index is created on col5 and col6. Here col4 is the datetime column. Based on this col4 the latest data is loaded from tab1 to unique view for every delta load. Yes, View will always have all the latest data from tab1 corresponding to the unique columns col5 and col6. And the view is used in upserting the data to table tab2 in schema db2.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available from SSH login, includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.